# Use preg_match to extract part of Serialized Data in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, serialization, preg-match

I am looking to extract some data from a serialized array stored in the MySql DB. I have inherited this and some records are broken but I can still extract some information. When I unserialize it does come back with an error so this out of the question unfortunately.

This is some of the serialized data: -

```
s:16:"current_postcode";s:8:"TT12 3TT";
```

I am looking to extract just the value from this using preg_match but I need some help trying to extract this in PHP.

Can you help?

Comment: Any valid reason you cannot just unserialize it? If you need to query a part of the serialized data then your database design is likely bad.

Comment: Hi ShiraNai7, I have inherited this database as already expressed above and some of the data is broken. That is why I want to do it this way. There are 400,000 records so I won't be trying to fix any of it any time soon.

Comment: Define "broken". You could also post the entire serialized string, not just a part of it.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't do that as it is sensitive information. It's broken as in there are offset issues caused by new lines that have not been submitted correctly.

Comment: And there are may be different missing characters, which will make your regexp not usable for all

Comment: Every time you put serialized data into a database, Codd kills a kitten. Are you trying to extract all values, or just postcodes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this one:

```
preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $data, $matches);
```

or

```
preg_match_all('/(?:s:16:|s:8:)"([^"]+)"/', $data, $matches);
```

but the last one is only valid if you always have s:16 or s:8 (the length of the data item) for the given part of data you are looking for. Otherwise it won`t be correct

Comment: How does this handle escaped quotes in strings? `s:12:"Some \"text\""`

Comment: The length does change as our postcodes can be as little as 5 characters and as high as 8. Could there be something put in that to cover that eventuality?

Comment: Basically I just want to return TT12 3TT from that code above.

Comment: What are the variations of this post code? I mean its values. Is there some common pattern?

Comment: Are they always capital letters + numbers?

Comment: Yes there are. Sometimes it can be like TT12 3TT or T1 3TT or T123TT.